# show modal pop and redirect

Tags: asp.net

I have a link on the page and i want when the user is pressing it, to evaluate a method where i check if the usser is logged in. If not, i want to show up a modal popup.
I know how to do the back-end checking and how to redirect the user but i have problems
with the link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                        OnClientClick="redirectToWishList()">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

When i press it, it does a full postback instead evaluating the method where i show up the modal pop.

Do you have any workaround to not fire a full postback but check the method where i am doing the redirect?

Ps: The method which has to fire:

```
 public void redirectToWishList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASP.usercontrols_loginpopup_ascx loginUserControl = (ASP.usercontrols_loginpopup_ascx)UtilsStatic.FindControlRecursive(Page, "loginPopUp");
    ModalPopupExtender modal = (ModalPopupExtender)loginUserControl.FindControl("loginPopUp");
    modal.Show();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call redirectToWishList as a function (including the parens): redirectToWishList()

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                        OnClientClick="redirectToWishList();return false;">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Also, if you return false in your function, you do not need to in the tag.

**UPDATE**

I misunderstood. The OnClientClick is for invoking JavaScript, not running methods in your code-behind. You need to OnClick instead.

Comment: I misunderstood. The OnClientClick is for invoking JavaScript, not running methods in your code-behind. You need to OnClick instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you return false from your `redirectToWishList` function?

You shouldn't need the `return false` in the LinkButton declaration.

Comment: I tried to prevent the postback to be fired. but seems it does not help.

Comment: Does your client method definitely fire?  Put an alert in it to verify that it fires.

Comment: No, the method is not firing. Instead, the hole page is refreshed.

Comment: It looks like redirectToWishList is a server side function, not a client side function?  It will need to post back to call this.